# How to modify /usr/share/maas/preseeds/generic

Tags: 14.04, server, maas, openstack

How to modify file /usr/share/maas/preseeds/generic , a need to enable proxy in MAAS to download boot images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set your HTTP/S proxy within the settings page in the MAAS web UI under `Network Configuration`.

Comment: It's not working when I set it in MAAS web UI. Do you know how to set it the other way?

Comment: @NebojsaKnezevic some logs would be helpful in determining what's not working. Check in `/var/log/maas`